# Syntax Error On Token "String", delete this token

Tags: java, android, syntax-error

thanks in advance for the help. I'm a beginner at Java and Android programming so my first app is just trying to pick rgb values from a photo after you take a picture. However, the last error is "Syntax Error On Token "String", delete this token". It's driving me crazy! It seems all my brackets are there, the syntax for each statement is correct, any ideas to what is going on? I'm using Eclipse if that makes a difference, the latest build. Here's the full code. The issue begins at the comment `/* SET TEXT FUNCTION TO THE FIELD USING SET TEXT METHOD*/.`

```
package com.example.firstapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity { //1

    TextView pixelcord, rgbvals; 
    ImageView iv;
    Button btn;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { //2

        /* GATHER THE INFORMATION FROM THE LAYOUT TO ORGANIZE APP*/
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /* SET ON CLICK LISTENER TO GET CLICK REPSONSE -- LAUNCH CAMERA AND TAKE PHOTO */
        /* SET VARIABLES FOR USE FROM EACH VIEW */
        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView); /* USE IMAGE VIEW FIELD*/
        pixelcord = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pixelcord); /* USE TEXT FIELD FOR PIXEL */
        rgbvals = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rgbvals); /* USE TEXT FIELD FOR RGB VALUES*/
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.takePhoto);

        /* SET INFORMATION OF WHAT TO DO UPON EACH CLIK*/
        iv.setOnTouchListener(imgSourceOnTouchListener);

/* =====================================CAMERA BUTTON=====================================*/        
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { //3

            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) { //4

                Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

            } //*4


        }); //*3
/* =======================================================================================*/        


        } /* END OF ON CREATE*/ //*2

    /* DECLARATION OF IMG TOUCH FUNCTION*/

    OnTouchListener imgSourceOnTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() { //5

        @Override

        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) { //6


            float eventX = event.getX();
            float eventY = event.getY();
            float[] eventXY = new float[] { eventX, eventY};

            Matrix invertMatrix = new Matrix(); 
            ((ImageView)view).getImageMatrix().invert(invertMatrix);

            invertMatrix.mapPoints(eventXY); 
            int x = Integer.valueOf((int)eventXY[0]); /* POTENTIALLY REDUNDANT*/
            int y = Integer.valueOf((int)eventXY[1]);


            /* SET TEXT FUNCTION TO THE FIELD USING SET TEXT METHOD*/
            pixelcord.setText("X:" String.valueOf(eventX) + "/ Y:" String.valueOf(eventY) ); 


            int touchedRGB = iv.getDrawingCache().getPixel(x,y);

            rgbvals.setText("Color Value" + "#" + Integer.toHexString(touchedRGB));
            rgbvals.setTextColor(touchedRGB);

            return true;

        } //*6


    }; //*5

    @Override

    protected void onActivityResult( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    { //7
        if(requestCode == 0)
        { //8
            Bitmap theImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            iv.setImageBitmap(theImage);

        } //*8
    } //*7


} //*1
```

Comment: Thank you all! That solved my problem, but now I have one more question. The photo button works and sends the picture to the view, but when I touch the image the program crashes as opposed to giving me the RGB value of the location touched. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a couple of `+` (concatination) operators. And you might also want to put a space after "X:" to make it "X: " so that the value prints nicely.

Your code should be:

```
pixelcord.setText("X: " + String.valueOf(eventX) + "/ Y: " + String.valueOf(eventY) );
```

Rather than:

```
pixelcord.setText("X:" String.valueOf(eventX) + "/ Y:" String.valueOf(eventY) );
```

Also you don't need the `String.valueOf(...)` function because Java will happily convert the float to a String for you. So your code can simply be:

```
pixelcord.setText("X: " + eventX + "/ Y: " + eventY );
```

Comment: That solved my problem, but now I have one more question. The photo button works and sends the picture to the view, but when I touch the image the program crashes as opposed to giving me the RGB value of the location touched. Any ideas why?

Comment: Running it on my phone it just says the application has stopped. I'm assuming it has to do with the imgSourceonTouchListener method

Comment: I will need to see an error to really help you. The only thing I noticed when having a quick look was: `int x = Integer.valueOf((int)eventXY[0]);` could just be: `int x = (int)eventXY[0];` although you need to be aware that numbers such as `5.453` would become `5` (the decimals are chopped off). That being said, this won't cause an error its just something I noticed.

Comment: Ok, I'm installing LogViewer, I should be able to tell you in a little bit

Comment: Ok, there is a runtime exception "Failure delivering result ResultINfo(who=null, request = 0, result = 0, data = null) to activity MainActivity. There's a runtime error at line 91 (the line that is supposed to give the touchedRGB variable the values. Does this help?

Comment: Also, if I comment out that line (the rgb value line) it gives me the coordinates like I want. Any thoughts?

Comment: Try this: `int touchedRGB  = ((BitmapDrawable)iv.getDrawable()).getBitmap().getPixel(x,y);`

Comment: If you just put a dummy value in, it works? `int touchedRGB = 0;`

Comment: Yeah! If I put in a dummy value it works. Also, thank you for working through this issue with me, I'm learning a lot about debugging now!

Comment: I'm not sure why its failing but at least we've found the problem statement. You can try narrowing it down by splitting that line into two and seeing where it crashes (I think it will be on the first part). `Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)iv.getDrawable()).getBitmap();`
`int touchedRGB = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);`

Comment: Also, do you know how to use the Eclipse debugger? Try putting a breakpoint on that line and seeing what the values are at that point, check to see if `iv` or `iv.getDrawable()/iv.getDrawingCache()` is `null`

Comment: And this is a shot in the dark but could you try: `int touchedRGB = ((ImageView)view).getDrawable()).getBitmap().getPixel(x, y);`

Comment: You were right it crashes at the `Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)iv.getDrawable()).getBitmap();` line

Comment: What's strange is that the program runs as intended on my computer's emulator, but not when I run it on an actual device. The rgb values show with no problem

Comment: Solved the problem -- I needed to lower the minimum SDK and target SDK values (I'm using an older phone). Thank you for all of your help, sorry for the wild goose chase!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need some more "+":

`pixelcord.setText("X:" + String.valueOf(eventX) + "/ Y:" + String.valueOf(eventY) );`

Answer (score 0):

```
pixelcord.setText("X:" String.valueOf(eventX) + "/ Y:" String.valueOf(eventY) );
```

should be

```
pixelcord.setText("X:"+ String.valueOf(eventX) + "/ Y:"+ String.valueOf(eventY) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing `+`

Replace line with

> pixelcord.setText("X:" + String.valueOf(eventX) + "/ Y:" + String.valueOf(eventY) );

Answer (score 0):

The setText() method takes a `String`. So you to use only string values, for this problem you have to concatenate with the `+` symbol

```
pixelcord.setText("X:"+ String.valueOf(eventX) + "/ Y:"+ String.valueOf(eventY) );
```